# Laravel Relationships Guidance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Could anyone please tell me how to create a relation between 3 tables.I have 3 tables. User, Profile and Post. Now I want to list all posts on the home page with user name form users table and profile image from the profiles table and posts from posts table.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to consider before suggesting any code. Your database structure, eloquent model classes and any other condition you want to apply before getting posts from database.

Hope, your `profiles` and `posts` table (both) contains `user_id` field.

You have to define two relationships.

In `Post` model define:

```
public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

In `User` model define:

```
public function profile() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
```

Now, before forwarding your $posts to view you may run this statement:

`$posts->load('user.profile);`

This will load relevant user and their profile within posts. Like this:

```
posts:[
    {...,
    user:{
        ...,
        profile:{...}
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Further reading recommended:

1. Belongs To Relationships
2. Nested Eager Loading